# Step Function stuck in "Running" state after 2 tries

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a Step Function that gets stuck in `running` state after it runs twice. The first 2 times it runs as expected.

The function checks the state of snapshots and updates the records in a DynamoDB table. If the snapshot is still in `creating` state, it will raise an exception.

`{
  "error": "SnapshotToolException",
  "cause": "{\"errorMessage\": \"There are still 1 snapshots in creating state.\", \"errorType\": \"SnapshotToolException\", \"stackTrace\": [[\"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", 5, \"lambda_handler\", \"checkSnapshotRecordsState()\"], [\"/var/task/dynamodb_control_utils.py\", 92, \"checkSnapshotRecordsState\", \"raise SnapshotToolException(log_message)\"]]}"
}`

```
{
  "Comment": "Triggers check DynamoDB snapshots records lambda function",
  "StartAt": "CheckSnapshots",
  "States": {
    "CheckSnapshots": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:function:checkDynamoDBSnapshotRecords",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": ["SnapshotToolException"],
          "IntervalSeconds": 120,
          "MaxAttempts": 20,
          "BackoffRate": 30
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Execution Steps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the `"BackoffRate": 30` to `"BackoffRate": 30.0`. Seems that omitting the `.0` decimal at the end tells the Step Function to wait 30 minutes as opposed to 30 seconds as the documentation suggested.

Comment: I'm getting similar issue. I'm triggering glue job, I can see that glue job is completed from console but step functions remain stuck at that for forever.